# Using a parameter of PHP and variables

Tags: javascript, php, html, get

I'm developing player of Google Drive and here what I see is the mirror
and 1 example:

```
$gdplay = http_request("https://gdriveplayer.to/embed2.php?link=https://drive.google.com/file/d/".$share['file']['file_id']."/view&subtitle=yes&button=no&encrypt=yes ");
$gdplayer = $gdplay;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($gdplayer);
$Frame = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0);
$srcf = $Frame->getAttribute('src');
```

This is working, but I want to add new mirror server.

For example I see and get new hosts

https://gdriveplayer.cc/embed2.php?host=gdrive&id=1LnGD2bVOh_p7EnA7fyC9rpk21-_YKqaZ&ahost=&aid=&lang=Default&sub=&poster=&onlylink=no

The result I found the iframe but as a code. When I try to add like the working code and get the element of src like this

```
$gdplaycc = http_request("host=gdrive&id=".$share['file']['file_id']."&ahost=&aid=&lang=Default&sub=&poster=&onlylink=no ");
    $gdcc = $gdplaycc;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($gdplayer);
    $Frame = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0);
    $srcc = $Frame->getAttribute('src');
```

It's error.

Comment: the iframe code entity encoded, so is just a string, you would need to [decode it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) into html before putting into domdocument

Comment: i want to make it automatically,anyway how to get text inside a page and show it as a html code?